# What techniques exist to create larger sheets of origami paper from smaller ones?

Tags: paper, origami

What techniques (if any) others have used to join smaller squares of paper together to create, as seamlessly as possible, a larger one to work with?

Comment: This is not so much a question on texture, tensile strength, specific application, etc., as it is wondering if anyone makes large squares of paper for all-around origami use.

Comment: I will try again: What techniques--if any, well I know how many origamists feel about tape or adhesives--to join four squares of paper together in such way as to make a larger sheet to work with...and with a minimal amount of visible evidence that this has been done?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this thread on the Origami Forum](https://snkhan.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5287), you probably want to use some form of adhesive, such as tape, glue, spray adhesive, or methyl cellulose to join the sheets.  It will create double-thickness at some points and texture differences (tape, for example, doesn't fold the same way paper does), and of course seams, so you do want to make sure those seams won't show in a prominent area of the finished model, or that you only used the joined paper for practice, and not a display model.